# Wrap HTML table cell text in span tags

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, preg-replace

Just trying to embrace the innerWords of some **td**-elements with `<span class="brc">Words</span>`.

```
<td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> Zeit für ein dududuDUELL </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> EloDrop </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> HighPINGklärtGG </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> BlaViShi </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> Bruteforce tv </td>
```

The td-class **views-field** cant't be used for it. My current codes is:

```
<?php

$url = "http://competitive.euw.leagueoflegends.com/de/ladders/euw/current/ranked_team_3x3";

preg_match('#<table class="views-table cols-6"[^>]+>[\w\W]*?</table>#i', file_get_contents($url), $match);
echo $match[0];

$brc = array("Zeit für ein dududuDUELL","OP Scheisse","Selbstzerstörungsknopf","EloDrop","HighPINGklärtGG","BlaViShi");
echo preg_replace(I dont know how this works);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$brc` is an array of strings you want to wrap with the `span` you could loop through them and use [`str_replace`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
foreach($brc as $str) {
    $match[0] = str_replace($str, '<span class="brc">'.$str.'</span>', $match[0]);
}
```

Comment: You should be able to replace your `preg_replace` line with my code and `match[0]` will contain the final string.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk($brc, function (&$elem) { $elem = "/" . preg_quote($elem) . "/"; });
echo preg_replace($brc, '<span class="brc">\0</span>', $match[0]);
```

The `array_walk` is just to add regex delimiters around the words and properly escape them, but you can also do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback);

```
$s = '<table class="views-table cols-6">
        <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> Zeit für ein dududuDUELL </td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> EloDrop </td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> HighPINGklärtGG </td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> BlaViShi </td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"> Bruteforce tv </td>
      </table>';
$s = preg_replace_callback('~<td(.*?)>(.*?)</td>~isu', function($m) {
    return sprintf('<td%s><span class="brc">%s</span></td>', $m[1], $m[2]);
}, $s);
print $s;
```

Output;

```
<table class="views-table cols-6">
    <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"><span class="brc"> Zeit für ein dududuDUELL </span></td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"><span class="brc"> EloDrop </span></td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"><span class="brc"> HighPINGklärtGG </span></td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"><span class="brc"> BlaViShi </span></td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-summoner-name-1"><span class="brc"> Bruteforce tv </span></td>
</table>
```